# Vim: how to regenerate a file using its undo file?

Tags: vim

I deleted a file by accident, but still have the undofile. Containing probably all the changes. Is there a way to retrieve this file using only the undo file?

Comment: Doesn't look like it according to [this post](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Restore-file-from-undo-td4440464.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with Vim, as:

- the undo changes are checksummed (so cannot be applied to an empty or old base file)
- undo only saves the actual changes, so you'd either must have touched all lines, or did all your edits to the file with your own Vim instance

The thread provided by Al G is very instructive; if you're desperate, you can try the attached patch, but I wouldn't nurture any hopes. Better pursue other paths, like filesystem recovery / backups (you do have backups, don't you?!)

Comment: It was something I typed just today. I used the patch and were able to recover a lot of partial lines which helped me a lot to retype it. I first tried to recover it with extundelete, which found the inode, but the contents were already unusable.

Comment: That patch unfortunately isn't in Vim's todo list, so if you think this is useful, please post a short link on vim_dev and ask for its inclusion.